# How to use .map() ? I want to select querySelectorAll() + .map() to return Array with Index(name)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create a variable array with index (name) = value, referring to   html, example of what this array would look like:

```
var array = [];
array['name'] = 'value';
array['car'] = 'Ferrari';
array['car2'] = 'BMW';
array['color'] = 'Red';
console.log(array);
```

In my Html I'm using the .map() function to get the values but the array that is formed has an automatic index, how to define the array's index so that it is equal to the name field??

```
<select multiple>
      <option value="car">Ferrari</option>
Array ['car'] = 'Ferrari' ;
```

```js
let list = document.querySelectorAll("option");
let items = Array.from(list).map(elem => elem.text);
console.log('items: '+items);
```

```html
<select style="width:130px ;"  multiple>
     <option value="car" selected>Ferrari</option>
     <option value="car2">BMW</option>
     <option value="color">Red</option>
     <option value="color2">Black</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Um, The way you want it is not an array, that is an object. `array['name'] = 'value';`

Comment: In your example you're allowed to select both car types and colours? How do you determine which colour goes on which car?

Comment: @Andy it's just an example, the colors and cars are in different selects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create an object with properties, not an array. If you are coming from another language, then it may be confusing that JavaScript uses array-like syntax to access properties (called [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#bracket_notation)).

You can use `reduce` because you are reducing multiple elements of an array to a single object:

```js
let list = document.querySelectorAll("option");
let items = Array.from(list).reduce((acc, elem)=> {
    const value = elem.getAttribute("value");
    acc[value] = elem.text;
    return acc;
}, {});
console.log(items);
```

```html
<select style="width:130px ;"  multiple>
     <option value="car" selected>Ferrari</option>
     <option value="car2">BMW</option>
     <option value="color">Red</option>
     <option value="color2">Black</option>
</select>
```